# Différence entre « en fait » et « de fait »

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Quelle est la différence entre ces deux expressions? Est-ce que vous pouvez me donner des phrases d'exemple pour comprendre mieux la différence?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

« De fait » introduit une explication, une confirmation de ce qui précède, on peut le remplacer par « effectivement » ou « en effet » :

> Ses parents sont très gentils et de fait j'ai été très bien accueilli.

« En fait » introduit une opposition à ce qui vient d'être dit, on pourrait le remplacer par « mais » ou « en réalité » :

> Christophe Colomb pensait être arrivé aux Indes, en fait il était dans les Antilles.

Answer (score 2):

You could translate « en fait » by "in fact", whereas « de fait » rather means "so"

> J’ai changé d’avis, en fait, je ne vais pas à la piscine

I changed my mind, in fact, I'm not going to the swiming pool (ie: actually)

> Je me suis blessé à la jambe, de fait, je ne vais pas à la piscine

I injuried my leg so I'm not going to the swiming pool

Comment: Actually, "en fait" should be translated as "actually"

Comment: @Random. Yeah, I was unsure about using "in fact" which is the literal translation for "en fait". May "in fact" be used in the case or should I actually use "actually" ?

Comment: I've always been told not to use "in fact" in my enlgish lessons, because it is a "false friend" and won't mean what we expect it to, so I don't really know what it actually means... but that could be an interesting question to ask to native english people :)

Comment: @Random Actually is usually translated into French by *en réalité*.   The answers to [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/53835/12918) might interest you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Jean pensait qu' il était arrivé à Cap- Haïtien, en fait qu' il se trouvait au Limbé.
2. Jean était malade,  il allait consulter son médecin, il avait pris soin de son état de santé, en effet, de fait,  il se trouvait en bonne.
3. Jean pensait aller se promener à la plage, au fait il restait à la maison.

Comment: Hi and welcome to French Language SE. I wonder if you could expand your answer a bit by explaining what the sentences mean and why "en fait" versus "de fait" was chosen. (Since you are new here, may I suggest that you also take the [tour] to familiarise yourself with the site?)